# Python can't import tika

Tags: python, module, apache-tika

I am having trouble importing tika in a python file. I have spent a lot of time googling and been unable to find anything. Here is the iPython command: import tika, and subsequent stack trace.

It occurs to me that there could be a problem with a module on which tika is dependent, such as requests, or urllib3. However, when I try to install those with pip, it says requirement already satisfied. I have also double checked the PYTHONHOME director, and I'm 99% sure it's correct.

```
    $ ipython
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
WARNING: Readline services not available or not loaded.
WARNING: Proper color support under MS Windows requires the pyreadline library.
You can find it at:
http://ipython.org/pyreadline.html

Defaulting color scheme to 'NoColor'

In [1]: import tika
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py in <module>()
     26 try:
---> 27     from . import urllib3
     28 except ImportError:

ImportError: cannot import name 'urllib3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9f3de0ba3e70> in <module>()
----> 1 import tika

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\tika\tika.py in <module>()
     18
     19 try:
---> 20     __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
     21 except ImportError:
     22     from pkgutil import extend_path

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py in declare_namespace(packageName)
   2161             # Ensure all the parent's path items are reflected in the child,
   2162             # if they apply
-> 2163             _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
   2164
   2165     finally:

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py in _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
   2096         path = module.__path__
   2097         path.append(subpath)
-> 2098         loader.load_module(packageName)
   2099         _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
   2100     return subpath

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\tika\tika.py in <module>()
     89     open = codecs.open
     90
---> 91 import requests
     92 import socket
     93 import tempfile

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\requests\__init__.py in <module>()
     50 # Attempt to enable urllib3's SNI support, if possible
     51 try:
---> 52     from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
     53     pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()
     54 except ImportError:

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py in <module>()
     27     from . import urllib3
     28 except ImportError:
---> 29     import urllib3
     30     sys.modules['%s.urllib3' % __name__] = urllib3
     31

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py in <module>()
      6 import warnings
      7
----> 8 from .connectionpool import (
      9     HTTPConnectionPool,
     10     HTTPSConnectionPool,

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in <module>()
      9
     10
---> 11 from .exceptions import (
     12     ClosedPoolError,
     13     ProtocolError,

C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.6\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 2 from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
      3     IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
      4 )
      5 # Base Exceptions

ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking at this, here is how I finally solved my issue.

I had been mistakenly assuming that the python-tika module was a fully packaged, ready to run version of tika. In fact, you need to download the java tika server from Apache, and it must be running when you use python-tika (you can easily just run the server on localhost).

The Python-tika module then allows you to make requests to this server from your python code. I probably should have known this but for some reason I didn't pick it up in the documentation.

Comment: spot on - just running the server .jar with defaults before running the examples on the github page solved the issue for me on windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have that module installed?

If not, just go to the Command Prompt and type `pip install tika`

Comment: Yes Tika is installed and you can see by the exception that python was able to find the module (I understand by the exceptions reference to tika.py that this is not a file path error).

Answer (score 0):

I think here is a good approach for installing tika on the Windows:
First, install java SE from this link:

https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Second, install a specific version of tika:

```
pip install tika==1.23
```

Third, download and run the tika server and tika app files from apache:

https://archive.apache.org/dist/tika/tika-server-1.23.jar

https://archive.apache.org/dist/tika/tika-app-1.23.jar

it should be fine, and you should be able to run tika in your application.

Comment: Verified again on April 25, 2021, with version 1.24 and it worked.